# java add int to int[]

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

How do I add a int to a int [] in Java. I want to do something like:

```
int limit = 10;
int[]array = {1, 9, 4, 20, 10, 20, 44};
int[]tooHigh;
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 1; j < array.length - i; j++) {
                    if (array[j] < array[j - 1]) {
                        temp = array[j - 1];
                        array[j - 1] = array[j];
                        array[j] = temp; 
if (array[j]>10){tooHigh.add(array[j))

                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: Use ArrayList so  you will be able to do `add`

Comment: Adding an int to an array is much more complex and difficult than adding it to a collection, because you have to completely recreate the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply, you cann't as the array is of fixed size, its size cannot be modified once declared and you didn't initialize that array called `tooHigh` which can result in some error if you try to access its member as it didn't reserve any space in memeory as you didn'y type `tooHigh = new int[size];`

what you want to use is [ArrayList](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_arraylist.asp) for you mission.

so instead of:

```
int[]tooHigh;
```

write:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

and don't forget to type :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

at the beginning of the file. so that you can write :

```
    arrayList.add(15);
    arrayList.add(10);
    arrayList.add(30);
    arrayList.add(5);
    arrayList.add(-1);
    arrayList.add(5);
```

and this is some example code to add and loop over the `ArrayList`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayList.add(15);
    arrayList.add(10);
    arrayList.add(30);
    arrayList.add(5);
    arrayList.add(-1);
    arrayList.add(5);
    
    for (Integer integer : arrayList)
        System.out.println(integer);
}
```

and this is the output:

```
15
10
30
5
-1
5
```

look how simple is that!

Answer (score 1):

Use ArrayList so you will be able to do `add`

```
List tooHigh=new ArrayList(Integer);
tooHigh.add(array[j])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 types of arrays in java:

1. **Static**

   - Have a fixed size; to do with it.

   ```java
       int size = 100;
       int[] toohigh = new int[size];

       for(int i = 0; i < toohigh.length; i++) {
           toohigh[i] = i+2;
       }
   ```
2. **Dynamic**

   - Have dynamic size; to do with it.

   ```java
      ArrayList<Integer> toohigh = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // give you default size = 10 & initially with zeros
      for(int i = 0; i < toohigh.size(); i++) {
           toohigh.add(i+2);

       }
   ```